# JavaScript function not showing passed values

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I have a custom JS function in a files myUtils.js as shown below with extra code within it. When I call it from another JS file it works fine, but when I try to call it from my VB.Net code it returns blank value for message. What could I be doing wrong here?

JS function:

```
DisplayMsg: function (message, title, template) {
        alert(message);
}
```

VB code

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Page.GetType, "script",     "parent.DisplayMsg('Saved successfully.','Saved','OK');", True)
```

Comment: You're passing a string literal to the `message` parameter - are you saying you get an alert box but with no content, or that you're not seeing the alert box at all? You said "returns blank value" but you're not returning anything from that method.

Comment: I get an alert box with no content

Comment: Then its not comeing from the VB code you provide - that passes a string literal as the `message` parameter. This question is unanswerable in its current form.

Comment: Try using the arguments object to see what data is being sent by VB. If you are unable to use `console.log("arguments",arguments)`, try something like ```DisplayMsg: function (message, title, template) {
        alert(message);
        alert(arguments.length);
        alert(arguments[0]);
}```

Answer (score -1):

`alert` function returns nothing, it just creates and show to user an alert box with message. Try simply return needed value from your function:

```
function DisplayMsg (message, title, template) {
  return message;
}
```

Comment: The value of message is blank